# Express $\frac{1}{y}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}$ in terms of $\ln$s

Tags: calculus

I know that $$\frac{1}{y}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}$$ can be written as:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\ln y+\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \ln y\right)^2$$
because if I take this last form, I can get to the form above by a few lines of algebra.

Assuming I don't know the second line, how could I go from the first line to the second line, knowing that I want $\ln$s in my expression?

Comment: Experience is really the only thing that can help you here because you have to know which terms you have to conjure up to add and subtract. There's multiple other formulas you could end up with, too, besides this one if your only goal is to "have $\ln$s"

Comment: The substitution $y=e^z$ is helpful here.